Question about redundant use of Riemann Mapping Theorem
 Theorem 1:  Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded simply connected open set and every boundary point of $\Omega$ is simple. If $(a,b,c)$ is a positively oriented triple of distinct points of $\partial \Omega$ and $(A,B,C)$ is a positively oriented triple of distinct points of $\partial \mathbb{D}$ then there is a conformal equivalence $\phi$ of $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\phi(a) = A, \, \phi(b) = B, \, \phi(c) = C$.
Caratheodory's Theorem: Suppose $D$ is a bounded simply connected region in the plane and every boundary point of $D$ is simple. Let $\phi : D \to \mathbb{D}$ be a conformal equivalence. Then $\phi$ extends to a homeomorphism of $\overline{D}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Let $Q^+ = \big\{ z = x+iy : y > 0, \, 0 < x < 1, \, \big|z-\frac{1}{2}\big| > \frac{1}{2} \big\}$.
I've read a proof of a theorem that says that:

The Riemann Mapping Theorem shows that there exists a confromal map $h : Q^+ \to \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half-plane. Caratheodory's Theorem shows that $h$ extends to a homeomorphism of the extended closure of $Q^+$, that is $\overline{Q^+} \cup \{ \infty \}$ onto $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$. Since $(0, 1, \infty)$ is a positively oriented triple in the extended boundary of $Q^+$, Theorem 1 shows that we may choose $h$ in such a way that $h(0) = 0, h(1) = 1$ and $h(\infty) = \infty$.


 Edit:  Suppose that $D$ is an open subset of the plane and $\zeta \in \partial D$. We will say that $\zeta$ is a simple boundary point if it has the following property: If $(z_n)$ is any sequence of points in $D$ with $z_n \to \zeta$ then there exists a continuous map $\gamma : [0, 1) \to D$ and a sequence $(t_n)$ in $[0,1)$ such that $t_n \le t_{n+1}$, $t_n \to 1$, $\gamma(t_n) = z_n$ and $\lim_{t \to 1} \gamma(t) = \zeta$.
In other words, $\zeta$ is a simple boundary point if every sequence in $D$ which tends to $\zeta$ lies on a curve in $D$ which tends to $\zeta$.

My question is: This doesn't implies that first affirmation with Riemann Mapping Theorem is reduntant? I mean.. I could use the Theorem 1 to show that there exists a such conformal map and then use the Caratheodory's Theorem to extend it on boundary to a homeomorphism without mention the Riemann Mapping Theorem. Is ok what I think, or not? Thanks!

What does it mean simple boundary point in the first statement?

@Conrad I've added an edit for clarifying what simple boundary point is, and an edit to Caratheodory's theorem (a weak version - says in my book)

I am still not sure what is your question - Caratheodory theorem is a generalization of RMT in a special case so it includes it there (in other words quoting Caratheodory is like quoting RMT plus some extra condition); is your question about if for a bounded simply connected set, the property of every point being simple is equivalent to the fact that the boundary is a simple (closed) curve? This indeed is true and is proved in Conway II for example

@Conrad No. So the proof firstly shows that there exists a conformal map from $Q^+$ to $\mathbb{H}$, after this extends the conformal map to a homeomorphism on the boundaries, and after this it says that theorem 1 shows that we can choose the conformal map with those properties $h(1) = 1, etc.$. From what I see, theorem 1 contains already the RMT because shows that there exists a conformal map between the two sets... so it won't be better for the proof to be like this: Use Theorem 1 for proving that a conformal map with those properties exists and then use Caratheodory to extend it

What I mean is if we can remove that RMT from the start of the proof and replace it with Theorem 1 because I think that Theorem 1 already contains existence from RMT

Theorem 1 is another generalization of RMT so again quoting it is like quoting RMT plus something extra - sure you can do it that way; so if you like, RMT is the foundation and you build on it various results (Theorem 1, Caratheodory etc) and of course when you try and prove something where those latter apply you can use them without directly quoting RMT since they already include it - so you are right if Theorem1 applies RMT is already included hence doesn;t need to be quoted directly, only Theorem 1

Thanks @Conrad . I understand now!

happy to be of help

@Conrad I have a few questions. I try to do my bachelor degree and to read some proofs and understand them. If you want, can you give me some email or something to ask you a few questions? Thanks, anyway for all!
